# Laravel Mix - Duplicated CSS within browser dev tools (Sass to CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

Currently I'm seeing multiple of the same styling within the dev tools. I'm using React and Laravel Mix and not sure why it's showing the same styling multiple times as I'm using React components importing sass files within the different components but it's not recognising the same css when compiling.

**Example:**

[image]

**Expected:**

It should only be showing the `@media` once and the single `.side-double` once.

**Laravel Mix file:**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const PurgeCSSPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');

//-- Website Mix --
mix.babelConfig({
   plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import', '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'],
});

mix.webpackConfig({
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    stats: {
        warnings: false,
    },
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'website/js/chunks/[chunkhash].js',//replace with your path
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@fonts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/website/styles/fonts'),
            '@images': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/website/images')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new PurgeCSSPlugin({
            paths: glob.sync('website/*',  { nodir: true }),
        })
    ]
});

mix.options({
    postCss: [
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
    fileLoaderDirs:  {
        fonts: 'website/fonts',
        images: 'website/images'
    }
});

mix.js('resources/website/index.js', 'public/website/js').react();
mix.version();
//-- Website Mix End --
```

**Updated**

Definition of style:

[image]

Where is the style included:

[image]

Comment: are you sure these are called at one place? seems like they are called twice

Comment: Does it seem duplicated only when running "watch" commands for developing (or related)? Or also when building for productions?

Comment: @Mtxz it's also when it's doing for production, development and watch

Comment: @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan they're called in different pages throughout the site, but not all the components are being used at these times. The issue might be that the compiler isn't working for react e.g. only using components when it needs to be

Comment: where are you getting these style definitions from? and can you add where you're linking them?

Comment: Search all your files for components/jsx which use 'side-double' in classes. If it's only one component, check if it is rendered twice due to automatic re-render, because of useState, for example.

Comment: as @NoamYizraeli asked, could you add the CSS asset include? Also check the source code of the page, and see if the include is doubled, or the style is inlined twice, or one of bot maybe.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli - I've updated question with few screenshots, it's like the webpack is compiling all the js files and importing the sass into css and not detecting the same style is already there

Comment: @Nulldroid - Please see above comment

Comment: @Mtxz - Please see above comment, i've updated the question

Comment: if you see its already implemented then you can remove it from the manual setting section

Comment: @NoamYizraeli - what do you mean? manual setting section?

Comment: you've mentioned the style already exists in the css and webpack adds it from the sass. remove it from one of them (easier would be from where you can control it (the css file))

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Ahh my bad, I meant that the sass is compiled by webpack within the javascript but if one sass file has already been compiled once it's duplicating the outputted css. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli check where are included home.sass and boiler-quotes.sass. what are the final CSS files included on your page, and from what SCSS files and imports they are coming? It's possible that one CSS file you create included both SCSS and so duplicate this part of the code. Then you include this built CSS containing duplicated code.

Comment: @Mtxz due to it being reactjs the sass gets compiled into the javascript, the site then imports the compiled javascript file "index.js". Is there a way for reactjs to compile but remove any duplicate styling or to only load css reacted for that page at the time? as I thought that's what components were for and import sass files in the individual places

Comment: Ah I see. Can you check the index.js compiled file? And verify if you see your CSS code multiple time in the dist build? Or only once?

Comment: @Mtxz - I can confirm that the css is within the build multiple times

Comment: Ok, so you should double-check all SCSS imports. Are you sure the SCSS file is not imported into multiple SCSS files? Cause you use a wildcard website/* import in webpack/mix. So it'll import very SCSS file. If one SCSS file includes another one, then it'll be included twice in the final build.

Comment: @Mtxz is there a way for webpack to detect duplicate imports?

Comment: I don't know. But I guess you better look yourself for double import, than supercharging webpack with something to check about it. As I asked you, are you importing SCSS files from others SCSS files, while wildcard loading SASS with webpack ?

Comment: @Mtxz - I've ran through all the different imports and the sass files are only being imported into components when they're required. They're not being double imported into other files.

Comment: And no components is loaded twice on your page? Idk much about react, but can you try to use "scoped" styles? That will only apply to the component.

Comment: @Mtxz for the time being I've resolved by sticking the styling within the main app.js until I figure out how where best to put the imports within the components as if components are loaded within the same page this is where duplication of styling is happening "I think".

Comment: Exactly, but "scopes" styles should prevent the component style from applying to something else than the component. Good luck :)